# Add property to an item in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, list, razor

So I'm just starting out with ASP.NET MVC, and I've run into an issue I just can't find an answer to.

I'm grabbing some data from an SQL database, and send it to the view with this code:

```
var listingsQuery = (from s in db.tblListings select s).OrderBy(s => s.listingID).Skip(100).Take(25);
var listings = listingsQuery.ToList();

return View(listings);
```

This works great, but I want to add a value in the list of results. Basically what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
foreach (var item in listings)
{
    this.Add("propertyType", "Home");
}
```

But obviously that doesn't work. I've tried doing ToArray() instead of ToList() and that got me nowhere.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - are you wanting to select more than one thing, along the lines of `(from s in db.tblListings select new { s, "Home" })`?

Comment: Derek, what are you trying to do? I suppose that this `foreach` is on your Controller, not on the View. But what is it supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm basically trying to add another property to each item in the list. Each item has an array of properties, so in the foreach in my View I'd be able to do @item.propertyType. propertyType doesn't exist in the DB, I'm just trying to add it to the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want to add a new property to each object in the List collection? If so, you can create a new type that inherits from whatever object type is in the list (hover over the listingsQuery variable - the type is inside the <> symbols) and add the new property to it:

```
public class MyNewType : ExistingTableType
{
    public string PropertyType { get; set; }
}
```

Then inside of your query, project the properties into this new type:

```
var listingsQuery = (from s in db.tblListings  
                     orderby s.listingID
                     select new NewType
                     {
                         listingID = s.listingID,
                         someOtherField = s.someOtherField
                     }
                    ).Skip(100).Take(25);
```

Now you can cycle through each record and assign a value:

```
foreach(var record in listings)
{
   record.ProperyType = "Home";
}
```

There are other ways of doing this as well (assuming you're using EF), for example, if you used raw SQL you can cast the result type directly into the new type (without having the map each field), but this should get you started.

Comment: This solves my original problem, but now when I try to add a Where I get "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Mountainside.Controllers.ListingController.MyNewType' and 'string'". My WHERE looks like this: .Where(listingOnOff => listingOnOff == "On Mountain")

Comment: I'd guess it's because you're not referencing the actual property in your lamda (the variable is a reference to the object and can be named anything; it has nothing to do with the actual field/property name). Maybe something like this instead, .Where(r => r.listingOnOff == "On Mountain")

Comment: That worked, thanks! Now I guess I have to figure out WHY it worked.

Comment: Read the Where() clause as - For each record named "r", check to see if r.listingOnOff is equal to "On Mountain". So "r" is a reference to one record in a collection of records. "r" is just a variable name that references a "record", it's not the actual field name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a new row to your listings collection you need to do listings.Add instead of this.Add

If you want to modify a value in your listing collection then you need to do

```
     foreach(var item in listings)
     {
       item.PropertyName = value;
     }
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to do originally, but the property is an int in the DB, and the value I need is a string. I also couldn't get .Add to work. I'm away from my work PC now so I'm not sure what the error was, I can post it tomorrow.

Comment: When I try to do item.PropertyName = "value"; I get the following error messsage: 'Mountainside.Models.tlbListings' does not contain a definition for 'PropertyName' and no extension method 'PropertyName' accepting a first argument of type 'Mountainside.Models.tblListings' could be found